# enable lightbox2(jquery plugin) slideshow with <ul>

Tags: jquery, slideshow, lightbox2

i am using lightbox2  v2.7 (https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/ ),
the demo shows the required structure is

```
 <a href...><img ..></a>
 <a href...><img ..></a>
```

but my html structure:

```
 <ul>
   <li> 
     <a href="original.jpg" rel="lightbox[album]" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption1">
    <img src="content/img/jiudianyuding/thumbnail.png">
    </a>
</li>
```

the original image   pop-up in a  modal div successfully,  but the slideshow features is gone..  i digged into the sourcecode, and has no good idea to do with this. any help will be preciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have figured out, set  same value of "data-lightbox" property to all images .